# AudioRecord not initializing on android 11 when app is in background

Tags: java, android

I have been implementing this functionality to record audio playbacks played on the device.

It is working fine when my app is in foreground, and I am getting pretty fine audio recordings, but it is throwing the below error whenever my app goes to background.

I have implemented this as a service and starting this service from another service which is a foreground service.
I have tried all of the configuration for audioFormat but audioRecord object is failing to initialize.

Below is the function where app is crashed at run time.

private final void startAudioCapture() {

```
    AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration config = new AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(mediaProjection)
            .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build();

    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
            .setSampleRate(8000)
            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
            .build();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord.Builder()
            .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
            .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
            .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(config)
            .build();
    audioRecord.startRecording();
    audioCaptureThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File outputFile = createAudioFile();
            writeAudioToFile(outputFile);
        }
    };

    audioCaptureThread.start();
    mIsRecording = true;
}
```

Errors:-
E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -1
E/AudioRecord: createRecord_l(1): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.Myapp.app.internal, PID: 18240
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.Myapp.app.AudioService@bfz0813 with Intent { act=AudioService:Start cmp=com.Myapp.app.internal/com.Myapp.app.AudioService }: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.

Note:- This works perfect for all android version less than 11.

Comment: Having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**Android 11** changes when foreground services can access the device's location, camera, and microphone. This helps protect sensitive user data.

**Camera and microphone foreground service types**
If your app targets Android 11 or higher and accesses the camera or microphone in a foreground service, you must include the camera and microphone foreground service types.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services